# Recycle view overlap items on scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hello everyone i am facing a problem with recycle view.
im using a recycle view with swipe to change item position functionality where user can change the position of items by long press items.

all items comes dynamical with different types of views.

everything is working good but when im trying to scroll the view then items displaying in recycle view are overlap each other.

i search on google and got the solution that is override the method .

```
 @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       return position;
   }
```

when im using this method in my adapter class then my swipe to change view functionality stop working.

can anyone explain my why it's happening..?

Here is whole adapter class

```
public class CreateEmailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CreateEmailAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "CreateEmailAdapter";

    public int position = 0;

    public ArrayList<CampaignData> List;

    private final OnStartDragListener mDragStartListener;

    public CreateEmailAdapter(ArrayList<CampaignData> List, OnStartDragListener mDragStartListener) {
        this.List = List;
        this.mDragStartListener = mDragStartListener;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView title;
        public ImageView imageView, imageView2, imageView3;
        RelativeLayout MainListView;


        public MyViewHolder(final View view) {
            super(view);

            parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

            MainListView = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.MainListView);

            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.MainTitle);

            imageView2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPopup);

            imageView3 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.movearrows);

            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.lytPatternColorDraw);

            parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view1) {

                    position = getAdapterPosition();

                    HandleResponse(title.getText().toString(), view1, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(mView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        CampaignData campaignData = this.List.get(position);

        holder.parentLayout.setTag(campaignData);

        String extraData = campaignData.getExtraData();

        String MediaType = campaignData.getMediaType();

        holder.MainListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        holder.title.setText(campaignData.getTitle());

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(campaignData.getimage());

        holder.imageView2.setTag(campaignData); 

        holder.imageView3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mDragStartListener.onStartDrag(holder);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        Collections.swap(List, fromPosition, toPosition);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
        List.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return List.size();
    }

//    @Override
//    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
//        return position;
//    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }


}
```

XMl file list_row.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff">

   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lytGrab"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lytPatternColor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/movearrows"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/movearrows" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lytPatternColorDraw"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MainTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lytPatternColor"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Title Here "
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--Copy images   -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytGrab"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPopup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/three" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your `list_row.xml` and screenshot of what you mean by "overlap"?